# How to selectbox optiones data-max attribute's data pass to inputbox max attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I want to access select Box's option's attribute max-data's value pass in to the input box max attribute.

MY CODE

```
<select onchange="valueGetter()">
    <option value='40' data-max=50 >40</option>
</select>
```

```
<input id="table" type=number min="1" max="">
```

I want to get "data-max" value 50 to input box "max" value to 50.

WHAT I TRYED

```
 function valueGetter(){
        $("#table").attr('max',$(this).find(":selected").data('data-max'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `max` not `data-max` in the jQuery.
2. The code will only run if the select *changes* so you can't test it with only one option.

```js
function valueGetter({ value }) {
  console.log(value);
  $("#table").attr('max', value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="valueGetter(this)">
  <option value=40 data-max=50>40</option>
  <option value=50 data-max=90>140</option>
</select>

<input id="table" type=number min="1" max="">
```

Comment: it showing error in my consol Uncaught ReferenceError: valueGetter is not defined
    onchange Ember

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer so it uses `onchange` in the HTML again. I've also reduced the complexity of the code in the function because you don't really need all that jQuery.